# how to get converted value in datatable

Tags: hibernate, jsf, primefaces

I am using primefaces 3.4 and JSF 2.0. I have a 2 tables one is client master and other is case master. When case master entry is done, only client ID(Foreign Key in case master) will be updated in case master table. I have used same scenario as given in primefaces showcase for auto complete.

user just enters some character and according to that name will be suggested. user selects one of them and  while saving it only client id will be saved in case master.Basically i have used converter.

When user add case entry it must be displayed in datatable. Now the problem is I have to show client name instead of client ID. Can any one suggest how can I achieve in datatable.

I have tried following

```
Created method in managed bean.   
value="#{caseUitility.clientName(case.id.clientID)}"
but failed.
```

> SEVERE: could not initialize proxy - no Session
>
> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session

Can any one suggest how can I achieve in datatable. should I create one more converter for the same client master which returns name of client. or any thing else?

I hope this is very silly things for all of you bravo but i really stack up over here since a day and half.

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1):

You have a [LazyInitializationException](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/LazyInitializationException.html). 
You are trying to access a hibernate generated proxy which is not initialized.

Initialize the proxy properly before it is accessed in web app by eagerly fetching the contents or by using [Hibernate.initialize(proxy)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html#initialize%28java.lang.Object%29).

Answer (score 0):

It seems an `entity` or a `field` you are going to access in your `clientName()` method is not queried from the database. You may overcome this issue by re-querying the `client` object or the relevant entity from the database in the `clientName()` method. 
Check your `stacktrace` and find the line that the exception is thrown and then you could find the lazily loaded `entity`. 
It is difficult to say something more without seeing your `clientName()` method and the line which throw the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the steps to get a converted value e.g. subject name for subject id:

1. create a method to get subject name in the Managed Bean class

```
public String getSubjectNameById(Integer subjectID)
    {
        String subjectName = getSubjectsService().getSubjectById(subjectID).getSubjectName();
        return subjectName;
    }
```

2. call the method from xhtml class in datatable column like this:

```
<p:column sortBy="#{QuestionsMB.subjectNameById}">
     <f:facet name="header">
         <h:outputText value="Subject :" />
     </f:facet>
     <h:outputText value="#{QuestionsMB.getSubjectNameById(question.subjectId)}" />
</p:column>
```

I hope this helps :)